# Python IO object discarding the data written

Tags: python, testing, io

I want to use an IO object which would discard all the data written. Something similar to Go's [io.Discard](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Discard). Is there any widely used library having this?

The obvious usage is within the tests.

I am aware of [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), but that one will hold the data in a memory buffer. I was thinking rather about sparing the memory for the test cases where the written content can be ignored.

If such thing is not widely used and I rather should write one my myself, what's the minimal implementation of an IO object?